# How to use dark mode in CSS with MacOS Mojave?

Tags: css, macos-darkmode

MacOS Mojave has been recently released with the Dark Mode option.

Is there a way to use it in web apps, with CSS?

Answer (score 3):

Use `prefers-color-scheme` media query:

```
/* Text and background color for light mode */
body {
  color: #333;
}

/* Text and background color for dark mode */
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  body {
    color: #ddd;
    background-color: #222;
  }
}
```

The `prefers-color-scheme` query supports three values: `dark`, `light`, and `no-preference`.

No polyfills are required, the media query code would be skipped if your browser doesn’t support it.

Note: It is supported in **Safari 12.1** and Safari Tech Preview 68. Safari 12 that ships with Mojave does not support the media query.

iOS, Chrome and Firefox don't support Dark Mode as of Oct 2018.